# Remove form tags but maintain input functionality

Tags: javascript

I found a piece of code that works pretty close to how I want. The end result is that when you type something in the input field a list of relevant options appears below based on the text input. You can then click on one of these options instead of having to type of the full string.

The only problem is that when i try and adapt this code to my existing project it breaks because the input field is wrapped in a form. How would I modify this code so that it functions in the exact same way without having to wrap the input tag in a form element? I.e. just have an input field.

```js
(
  function()
  {

      var lookFor = [
          "Paris",
          "Canada",
          "England",
          "Scotland",
          "Brazil",
          "Manila",
          "Atlanta"
      ];

      var form = document.getElementById("theForm");
      var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
      var searchInput = form.search;

      // first, position the results:
      var node = searchInput;
      var x = 0;
      var y = 0;
      while ( node != null )
      {
          x += node.offsetLeft;
          y += node.offsetTop;
          node = node.offsetParent;
      }
      resultsDiv.style.left = x + "px";
      resultsDiv.style.top  = (y + 20) + "px";
      
      // now, attach the keyup handler to the search field:
      searchInput.onkeyup = function()
      {
          var txt = this.value.toLowerCase();
          if ( txt.length == 0 ) return;

          var txtRE = new RegExp( "(" + txt + ")", "ig" );
          // now...do we have any matches?
          var top = 0;
          for ( var s = 0; s < lookFor.length; ++s )
          {
              var srch = lookFor[s];
              if ( srch.toLowerCase().indexOf(txt) >= 0 )
              {
                  srch = srch.replace( txtRE, "<span>$1</span>" );
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  div.innerHTML = srch;
                  div.onclick = function() {
                      searchInput.value = this.innerHTML.replace(/\<\/?span\>/ig,"");
                      resultsDiv.style.display = "none";
                  };
                  div.style.top = top + "px";
                  top += 20;
                  resultsDiv.appendChild(div);
                  resultsDiv.style.display = "block";
              }
          }
      }
      // and the keydown handler:
      searchInput.onkeydown = function() 
      {
          while ( resultsDiv.firstChild != null )
          {
              resultsDiv.removeChild( resultsDiv.firstChild );          
          }
          resultsDiv.style.display = "none";
      }
     
  }
)();
```

```css
.searchInput {
    width: 200px;
}
#results {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: lightyellow; 
    z-index: 10;
}
#results div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white; 
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
    
#results div:hover {background: lightblue;}
    
#results div span {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<form id="theForm">
Search for: <input name="search" class="searchInput"/>
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: *it breaks because the input field is wrapped in a form* Why does having a form tag in your existing project break it? You might want to fix that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because in this section of code it relies on the `form` element to get the `input` element:

```
  var form = document.getElementById("theForm");
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
  var searchInput = form.search;
```

Other than that the `form` isn't needed. As such you could instead make it:

```
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
  var searchInput = document.getElementsByClassName("searchInput")[0];
```

Or instead change your `input` element to have an `id` of `"searchInput"` instead of a `class` and do:

```
  var resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
  var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchInput");
```